# Javascript | Splice removing the wrong item from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use `.splice` to remove an item from an array that I have in Angular.

The array is actually a `BehaviourSubject` so that in other components I can watch for the changes and reflect them through the application.

I have a method which will get all of the users from the Behaviour Subject currently...

```
getUsers(): UIUser[] {
    return this.users$.getValue();
}
```

As you can see, it literally just returns the value of the behaviour subject at the given time.

I thought the issue originally was because maybe the `getUsers` method is changing before I've even completed the method for some reason, so I cloned it and I am still getting the same result, which is the wrong item is being removed.

I have a method

```
deleteUser(deletedUser: User): void {
    const users: User[] = this.getUsers();

    const index: number = users.findIndex(user => {
        return user.id === deletedUser.id;
    });

    this.setUsers(users.splice(index, 1));
}
```

This for some reason removes the wrong item from the array.

The `setUsers` method just does this:

```
setUsers(Users: User[]): void {
    this.users$.next(users);
}
```

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane Doe'
  }
]
```

If I call `deleteUser(user)` with the user referencing `John Doe` the output will be:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
]
```

Whereas it should be the opposite way round, John Doe should be deleted and Jane Doe should remain.

Comment: Could you include the sample data and output?

Comment: splice() returns the element(s) removed, why are using that for setUsers, wouldnt you want the modified array?

Comment: @PatrickEvans that is exactly what I want, sorry I think I'm all over the place here. What you're saying though, is exactly what it happening. Should I just literally call `users.splice(index, 1)` and then return users?

Comment: Yes do the lone splice call and then do `setUsers(users)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you put this as an answer so I can accept please. I think I completely misunderstood what splice did / does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) returns the removed elements from the array and not the modified array. The original array will have been mutated in-place

For example:

```
var temp = [2,4,8,16];
var ret = temp.splice(1,2);
console.log(ret); //logs [4,8]
console.log(temp); //logs [2,16]
```

Simply call splice on its own and then pass `users` to your setter

```
users.splice(index,1);
setUsers(users);
```